# TYPO3 tx_news dateMenu - only Year - without Month

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news, typo3-10.x

i search for a TYPO3 tx_news dateMenu Solution only for the Year. Like this:

- 2019 (8)
- 2020 (12)
- 2021 (3)

Click on the Year, the Filter works only for the Year.
(*Show in the "news_list" all News from the active Year.*)

```
/typo3conf/ext/news/Resources/Private/Templates/News/DateMenu.html
```

here is a DateMenu with Year and Month.

Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adopt the `DateMenu.html` with something like this

```html
<f:section name="content">
    <div class="news-menu-view">
        <ul>
            <f:for each="{data.single}" key="year" as="months">
                <li>
                    {year}
          <f:link.action action="list" pageUid="{listPid}" arguments="{overwriteDemand:{year: year}}">{year}</f:link.action>
                </li>
            </f:for>
        </ul>
    </div>
</f:section>
```

Regarding the sum: this should be possible with the `<f:variable />` viewhelper initializing with `0` and reuse the `<f:for each` from the original template. I don't write the full example because can't currently test it myself